# Java GWT remoteLoggingServlet - can I configure java.util.Logging to send this to a log file?

Tags: gwt, logging, gwt-rpc, java.util.logging

Is it possible to get messages received on the server, from client side logging via the remoteLoggingServlet in GWT to write to a file?

http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging

I have GWT Logging set up successfully in my .gwt.xml

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINE"/>

<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
```

And the remote logging servlet set up:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>remoteLoggingServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>remoteLoggingServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/my.app.class.name/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I see my error messages on the development console.

I had hoped since the remote logging service

http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/logging/server/RemoteLoggingServiceUtil.java&is_navigation=1

appears to use java.util.Logging under the covers, that I would be able to configure this to log to a log file, so that I could see what errors users were getting on the client side, to diagnose some performance problems.

Has anyone had any luck configuring messages to go somewhere other than client side displays?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth - I have decided to work around this by reimplementing my own 
RemoteLoggingServiceImpl and RemoteLoggingServiceUtil

And switching these from using java.util.Logging to using Log4j once the messages are on the server side.